# Assigning a id+index value to a form field for manipulation using Alpine Js / Javascript in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, alpine.js, laravel-9

Environment:
Laravel 9,
Alpine Js,
TailWinds CSS, Vanilla Js

I am trying to do value replacement in a form field when a user enter " to inch or ' to ft.  I have implemented an 'add another row' functionality to the page which ends up giving me **multiple fields with the same id**.

I don't know how to highlight a particular line of code so I added <!-- HERE ----> (2 places) to the description field code below...

```
<!--  PO Lines Below  -->

<!--  Row 1 Fields  -->
    <div class="row" x-data="handler()">
        <div class="col">

         <template x-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">

            <div id="po_line" class="my-4">

               Line: <strong x-text="index + 1"></strong>
                    <label for="qty">Qty: </label>
                    <input x-model="field.qty" type="number" class="form-control rounded-lg text-sm" name="qty[]" value="" style="width:90px" />
                       <label for="part_num" class="ml-3">Part #: </label>
                       <input x-model="field.part_num" type="text" class="form-control rounded-lg text-sm" name="part_num[]" value="" style="width:200px"   />
                         <label for="descrip" class="ml-3">Descrip: </label>

                      <!-- HERE ---->    <input x-model="field.descrip" type="text" class="form-control rounded-lg text-sm" name="descrip[]" value="" style="width:300px"  id="descrip_id"   onblur="replaceQuotes()" />

                        <label for="cost" class="ml-3">Cost: </label>
                        <input x-model="field.cost" type="number" class="form-control rounded-lg text-sm" name="cost[]" value=""  style="width:110px"  step="0.01" min = "0"  />
                         <a href="#scroll" class="bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-500 text-white h-9 py-1 px-2 rounded-lg inline-flex items-center"  @click="removeField(index)">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash mx-1" style="font-size: 0.9rem;"></i>

                                        </a>
                                </div>
<!--  Row 2 Fields  -->

                  <div id="po_line" class="my-4">

                  Line: <strong x-text="index + 1"></strong>
                  <label for="qty">Qty: </label>
                  <input x-model="field.qty" type="number" class="form-control rounded-lg text-sm" name="qty[]" value="" style="width:90px" />
                  <label for="part_num" class="ml-3">Part #: </label>
                  <input x-model="field.part_num" type="text" class="form-control rounded-lg text-sm" name="part_num[]" value="" style="width:200px"   />

                       <label for="descrip" class="ml-3">Descrip: </label>

                <!-- HERE ---->   <input x-model="field.descrip" type="text" class="form-control rounded-lg text-sm" name="descrip[]" value="" style="width:300px" id="descrip_id"     onblur="replaceQuotes()" />
                 
               <label for="cost" class="ml-3">Cost: </label>
                 <input x-model="field.cost" type="number" class="form-control rounded-lg text-sm" name="cost[]" value=""  style="width:110px"  step="0.01" min = "0"  />
                <a href="#scroll" class="bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-500 text-white h-9 py-1 px-2 rounded-lg inline-flex items-center"  @click="removeField(index)">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-trash mx-1" style="font-size: 0.9rem;"></i>

                                        </a>
                                </div>
```

The line of code in question is this:

```
<label for="descrip" class="ml-3">Descrip: </label>
<input x-model="field.descrip" type="text" class="form-control rounded-lg text-sm" name="descrip[]" value="" style="width:300px" id="descrip_id"     onblur="replaceQuotes()" />
```

Here is the working javascript code for replaceQuotes() - Works with first instance only

```
<script>

<!-- Replace Quotes in Form -->

function replaceQuotes() {
                  
        var x = document.getElementById("descrip_id");
                 
        x.value = x.value.replace(/\"/g, " inch ")
        x.value = x.value.replace(/\'/g, " ft ")

<!-- Add a row of fields -->

function handler() {
                return {
                  fields: [],
                  addNewField() {
                      this.fields.push({
                           qty: '',
                           part_num: '',
                           descrip: '',
                           cost: ''
                       });
                    },
                    removeField(index) {
                       this.fields.splice(index, 1);
                     }
                  }
             }
                           }

             </script>
```

This code use REGEX matching to replace " with inch and ' with ft.

This code works fine on the first id='descrip_id' which is the first row or first instance of id='descrip_id'.  But on any subsequent rows do not get changed.

I have tried to concatenate the index from Line # which uses Alpine JS x-text.

I have also tried to pass this.id inside the function like replaceQuotes(this.id) and then add an id argument inside the function, but can't get either to work.

**So questions are:**

**1) How can I concatenate index onto id='descrip_id' to get a unique id such as id='descrip_id_1' ?**

I have tried id='descrip_id'.<x-text="index"> and id='descrip_id'+<x-text="index">

I would assume then I would just need to pass index with the function call?

-OR-

**2) How can I pass the active ID to the function and have it manipulate the data in the CURRENT descrip_id field only?**

Also tried, replaceQuotes(this.id)  then in Javascript function replaceQuotes(id) and replaceQuotes($id)  with x being assigned to id in the body of the function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an Alpine.js attribute you can use any JS (but not HTML the way you tried). So the correct method to create dynamic `id` attributes is just to use template literals and pass the active item's index to the `replaceQuotes` function.

```
<input x-model="field.descrip" 
       type="text" 
       class="form-control rounded-lg text-sm"
       name="descrip[]" 
       value="" 
       style="width:300px" 
       :id="`descrip_id${index}`" 
       @blur="replaceQuotes(index)" />


<script>
function replaceQuotes(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(`descrip_id${id}`)

  x.value = x.value.replace(/\"/g, " inch ")
  x.value = x.value.replace(/\'/g, " ft ")
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this and while it does add an id ="descrip_id0" to the form field, for some reason, it is not passing the index to the function on the OnBlur event.  

**select:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onblur (select:1:15)**

which is strange, because there is another function just below to remove a row of input fields that uses this:  @click="removeField(index)" and it works just fine.

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem.  Dauros said to use '@blur' and I was still using onblur.    When changed to '@blur', the code works perfectly.  Thanks!     BTW, I had to add '@blur' to the solution on the line above as StackExchange thought I was tagging someone, it should be '@blur' with NO quotes, see Dauros solution for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way using [`x-bind`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind)

it will be like `x-bind:id="'descrip_id'+index"`

```
<input x-model="field.descrip" 
   type="text" 
   class="form-control rounded-lg text-sm"
   name="descrip[]" 
   value="" 
   style="width:300px" 
   x-bind:id="'descrip_id'+index`"
  />
```

You can bind whatever attributes you want to create dynamically like this.